# CPU spin in popen()

Tags: c, posix, libc

Here's my code piece:

```
FILE *f;
char cmd[4096] = {0};

snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "echo -n \"%s\" | openssl md5 -hex 2>/dev/null | sed 's/^.* //g'", input);
if (NULL == (f = popen(cmd, "r"))) {
    perror(popen);
}
```

I got cpu spin in popen() and here's my callstack:

```
#0  0xf54d21cc in ?? () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xf4395eb3 in fork () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xf435b1d9 in _IO_proc_open () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0xf435b525 in popen () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

I have no idea how this happened.
Is there any "input" that could cause this happen?

Comment: is the input sanitized?

Comment: It looks like the `sed` command tries to do its best to reduce the output to a minimum.

Comment: What happens when you run this on a plain commandline in parts and `time` every step, instead of piping everything into the next command?

Comment: you are calling `perror(popen);`, perhaps you want to say `perror("popen");`.